# What are the advantages of returning -1 instead of null in indexOf(...)?

Tags: kotlin, language-design

When calling `List.indexOf(...)`, what are the advantages of returning `-1` rather than `null` if the value isn't present?

For example:

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "c")
val index = list.indexOf("d")

print(index) // Prints -1
```

Wouldn't it be a cleaner result if index was `null` instead? If it had an optional return type, then it would be compatible with the elvis operator `:?` as well as doing things such as `index?.let { ... }`.

What are the advantages of returning `-1` instead of `null` when there are no matches?

Comment: @Myszsoda he is asking why it works the way it does

Comment: I would say "to be compatible with java's" [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Rather than "Why was the language designed that way" which is basically unanswerable, a somewhat better question might be "What are the advantages to having .indexOf return -1 instead of null for no matches?" Also, while the question as it stands should be closed (and I voted to do so) 4 downvotes seems a little harsh...

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, I'll edit that in.

Comment: @Andy close vote rescinded. Nice edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just speculations but i could think of two reasons:

The first reason is to be compatible with Java and its [List.indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)

As the documentation states:

> Returns:
>      the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element

The second reason is to have the same datatype as [kotlins binarySearch](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/binary-search.html).

> Return the index of the element, if it is contained in the list within the specified range; otherwise, the inverted insertion point (-insertion point - 1). The insertion point is defined as the index at which the element should be inserted, so that the list (or the specified subrange of list) still remains sorted.

Where the negative values actually hold additional information where to insert the element if absent. But since the normal `indexOf` method works on unsorted collections you can not infer the insertion position.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the definitive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165038/#57165570) of @Burdui, another reason of such behavior is that `-1` return value can be expressed with the same primitive `Int` type as the other possible results of `indexOf` function.

If `indexOf` returned `null`, it would require making its return type nullable, `Int?`, and that would cause a primitive return value being boxed into an object. `indexOf` is often used in a tight loop, for example, when searching for all occurrences of a substring in a string, and having boxing on that hot path could make the cost of using `indexOf` prohibitive.

On the other hand, there definitely can be situations where performance does not so matter, and returning `null` from `indexOf` would make code more expressive. There's a request [KT-8133](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8113) to introduce `indexOfOrNull` extension for such situations.

Meanwhile a workaround with calling `.takeIf { it >= 0 }` on the result of `indexOf` allows to achieve the same.